# SQL Server High Frequency Inserts

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, entity-framework

I've a system where Data is being inserted through SP that's called via WCF Service.

In system, we have currently 12000+ actively logged in Users who will be calling WCF service at every 30 seconds (effectively min 200 requests per second).

On SQL Server side, CPU Usage shoots to 100% and when I examined, > 90% of time was spent in DB Writes. This affects overall server performance.

I need suggestion to resolve this issue so that we have less DB write operations and more CPU remains free.

Am open to integrate any other DB Server, use Entity Framework or any other ORM combination if needed. I need to have solution to handle this issue.

Other information that might be helpful:
Table has no indexes defined
Database has growth factor set to 200MB.
SQL Server Version is 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SImple solution: back the writes. Do not call into the sql server for every insert.

Make a service that collects them and calls them more coarsely. The main problem is that transaction handling is a little heavy cost wise - in cases like that it may make sense to batch them.

Do not call a SP for every row, load them into a temp table and then process them in bulk (or use a table variable to provide the sp with multiple lines of information at once).

This gets rid of a lot of issues, including a ton of commits (you basically ask for like 200 TPS which is quite heavy and not needed here).

How you do that is up to you - but for something that heavy I would stay away from an ORM (Entity Framework is hilarious in not batching anything - that should be tons of sp calls) and use handcrafted sql at least for this part. I love ORM's but it is always nice to have a high performance hand crafted approach when needed.

Comment: This SP also checks existing records in same table. Is it possible to have your suggestion included in SP? Any ideas, insights will be great.

Comment: Yes. So what? Load into temp table, have SP process the temp table, or use a table variable to run tons of rows into the SP in one call. I never said "do not use a SP at alL", just "do not use one calling it it line per line". Move towards processing a set of rows at the same call.

Comment: Ok. Let me see and I'll update here. Thanks for the idea @TomTom

Comment: temp table is getting deleted automatically. :(

Comment: @SanketShah A session level temp table survives till transaction end. Put ata there, call procedure.

Comment: I get your point, but this is now a trivial trouble. Have checked queries and still - max time goes in SELECT and UPDATE queries. No idea what's going wrong. I'll probably try to share SP here.